# Go lang convert os.File output to String

Tags: go

How to convert Os.File output into string instead of printing to shell.
I am using github.com/kr/pty library to execute commands.

How can convert the output to sting instead of printing to console.

f belongs to Os.File in below example. How to convert it to string.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/kr/pty"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func run_command(cmd string){
    c := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd)
    f, err := pty.Start(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)
}

func main() {
    run_command("ls -lrt");
}
```

Comment: `kr/pty` writes to the terminal, that's actually the whole point of it. If you just want the program's stdout, you should use `os/exec` directly. It even has [an example](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) to show you how, you just need to `string(out)` on the resulting `[]byte`.

Comment: If you really want to re-read the file (assuming it's an actual file, but I believe `kr/pty` writes to the console, so there's nothing to read back), you can always use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) on the `*os.File`. But again: the file `pty` opens is a terminal file descriptor, it just displays the contents, you don't be able to read them back.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)
```

you can do

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(&buf, f)
asString := buf.String()
```

Answer (score 2):

An *os.File is an io.Reader. There are a few ways to convert the contents of an io.Reader to a string using the standard library.

The strings.Builder approach might perform better than the other approaches because strings.Builder does not allocate memory when converting the accumulated bytes to a string. This performance benefit is probably negligible in the context of the question.

Otherwise, the choice of approach is a matter of taste and opinion.

**[strings.Builder](https://godoc.org/strings#Builder)**

```
var buf strings.Builder
_, err := io.Copy(&buf, f)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
s := buf.String()
```

**[bytes.Buffer](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer)**

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
_, err := buf.ReadFrom(f)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
s := buf.String()
```

**[ioutil.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll)**

```
p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
s := string(p)
```

Comment: Does ioutil.Read need to be ioutil.ReadAll?